# App rejected by Google due to "HTTP requests"

Tags: android, react-native, google-play, google-developers-console

I submitted an update to my app on google play for review and it got rejected with the message saying:
We found an issue in the following area(s): HTTP requests

I inspected all APIs and one API returned with a response code 500.
My question is that does google monitor all APIs response codes during review? I couldn't find anything specific from the pre-launch reports and so this is the only area I think google could have rejected the app for since a previous version is live on the play store. [App rejection screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUnXN.png)

I have added the rejection screenshot.

Comment: There is also other issue they mentioned that icon or button which is not working which is broken functionality.

Comment: I think that's categorization of the issue of which the HTTP requests issue falls under. No errors of unresponsive are generated, only warnings.

Comment: Did you figure out the issue. I got the same error recently and I don't really understand what they mean.

Comment: I just filed an appeal and they sent an email saying that my appeal was successful and that I should resubmit the app. Pretty confusing.